# Is there an API call to check your existing rate limit quota for the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook has a rate limit for using their Graph API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

Is there an API call to check your remaining quota?

Comment: Have you ever found anything?

Answer (score 3):

There's no API, but they do return your current quota usage in the HTTP response headers for Graph API requests.  The header is called [X-App-Usage](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting) and is a JSON string that looks like this:

```
{
  "call_count"    : x, 
  "total_time"    : y, 
  "total_cputime" : z
}
```

> The values for x, y and z are whole numbers representing the percentage used values for each of the metrics. When any of these metrics exceed 100 the app will be rate limited.

You can monitor it with each request and throttle your application accordingly.

Comment: for me those values are all 0and I am rate limited

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is no call to get the current remaining quota, so you should always check if the call was successful in your error handling.